# How to disable default website in Magento 2.2 multi-store?

Tags: multistore

How can I disable the default website in a **Magento 2.2** multi-store setup? I have 3 websites with their own store and store views. The main website needs to be taken down. The URL for that main website is also used for the backend admin pages. When I go into the `Stores > All Stores > Store View` page, the status selection box is grayed out. I understand that maybe the default store view cannot be disabled, but how can I take the website down then, but still have the other websites work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can change the admin URL to something else admin.yourdomain.com. You can do this in `Admin > Store > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Admin Base URL`.

Note: First you need to set up the same virtual host that points to the same Magento installation.

Once you are running admin with different URL you can stop your main domain.

There are some other ways but for that, we need to know why you want to take off the website.